# Algebraic Dynamic Programming breakdown of a simple problem (e.g. climbing staircase)

Tags: dynamic-programming

I found recently about Algebraic Dynamic Programming. As I understand, it's a formalization that immensely simplifies developing solutions for DP problems.

I spent a few days trying to grok it, to no avail. Perhaps in part it's because papers on ADP seem to require strong background in Formal Language theory, which I don't have. But lack of resources on ADP doesn't help either.

I'd really appreciate if someone acknowledgeable could show a step-by-step solution that applies ADP to a simple DP problem. Incidentally, the paper¹ has included multiple examples, but they left me with more questions than answers. It is because the paper overwhelms with a bunch of complex definitions, some of which *(such as definition of `~~~` and `...` functions)* are even defined much later after their actual use. It also doesn't help that examples chosen are not the simplest. So when I look for example at "El Mamun's problem" solution, I see disconnected code pieces with a bunch of missing parts, which author magically calls a solution. Maybe it could've helped had author posted a full compilable solution, but that didn't happen.

So let's say, "climbing staircase" is a straightforward problem, which allows to concentrate on ADP rather than the problem. It sounds like:

> You are climbing a staircase that has `n` steps. Each time you can either climb `1` or `2` steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

Can someone show an ADP breakdown of it? Or really, I don't mind if you're going to prefer some other simple problem to demonstrate an ADP approach.

For the record: a "DP" solution to it in Haskell:

```
solve1StepOrMore :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
solve1StepOrMore prevSteps lenLadder
      | lenLadder == 0 = step2
      | otherwise      = solve1StepOrMore [step2, step1 + step2] (lenLadder - 1)
      where
        step1 = prevSteps !! 0
        step2 = prevSteps !! 1

solve lenLadder
      | lenLadder == 0 = 0
      | otherwise      = solve1StepOrMore [0,1] lenLadder

main = do
  print $ (show $ solve 0) ++ ", expected 0"
  print $ (show $ solve 1) ++ ", expected 1"
  print $ (show $ solve 2) ++ ", expected 2"
  print $ (show $ solve 3) ++ ", expected 3"
  print $ (show $ solve 4) ++ ", expected 5"
```

---

1. A Discipline of Dynamic Programming over Sequence Data, [link](https://bibiserv.cebitec.uni-bielefeld.de/adp/ps/adp_discipline.pdf)
2. Implementing Algebraic Dynamic Programming in the Functional and the Imperative Programming Paradigm, [link](https://bibiserv.cebitec.uni-bielefeld.de/adp/ps/adp_implementing.pdf)